# Exporting PyTorch Lightning model to ONNX format not working

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, pytorch-lightning

am using Jupyter Lab to run. It has pre-installed tf2.3_py3.6 kernel installed in it. It has 2 GPUS in it.

```
PyTorch Lightning Version (e.g., 1.3.0): '1.4.6'
PyTorch Version (e.g., 1.8): '1.6.0+cu101'
Python version: 3.6
OS (e.g., Linux): system='Linux'
CUDA/cuDNN version: 11.2
How you installed PyTorch (conda, pip, source): pip
```

I am saving the best model in checkpoint.

I am doing multi-label classification using `Hugging face model`. After training the model I want to export the model using ONNX format. The input is `attention mask`, `input ids`.

**Here is the DataModule Class**

```
N_EPOCHS = 30
BATCH_SIZE = 10

class  SRDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    
    def __init__(self, X_train,y_train, X_test,y_test, tokenizer, batch_size=8, max_token_len=512):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.train_df = X_train
        self.test_df = X_test
        self.train_lab = y_train
        self.test_lab = y_test
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_token_len = max_token_len

    def setup(self, stage=None):
        self.train_dataset = SRDataset(
          self.train_df,
          self.train_lab,
          self.tokenizer,
          self.max_token_len
        )

        self.test_dataset = SRDataset(
          self.test_df,
          self.test_lab,
          self.tokenizer,
          self.max_token_len
    )

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
          self.train_dataset,
          batch_size=self.batch_size,
          shuffle=True,
          num_workers=10
        )

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
          self.test_dataset,
          batch_size=self.batch_size,
          num_workers=10
        )

    def test_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(
          self.test_dataset,
          batch_size=self.batch_size,
          num_workers=10
        )
```

**Here is the model class:**

```
class SRTagger(pl.LightningModule):

  def __init__(self, n_classes: int, n_training_steps=None, n_warmup_steps=None):
    super().__init__()
    self.save_hyperparameters()
    self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained(BERT_MODEL_NAME, return_dict=True)
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, n_classes)
    self.n_training_steps = n_training_steps
    self.n_warmup_steps = n_warmup_steps
    self.criterion = nn.BCELoss()

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, labels=None):
    output = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    output = self.classifier(output.pooler_output)
    output = torch.sigmoid(output)    
    loss = 0
    if labels is not None:
        loss = self.criterion(output, labels)
    return loss, output

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
    labels = batch["labels"]
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    
    self.log("train_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return {"loss": loss, "predictions": outputs, "labels": labels}

  def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
    labels = batch["labels"]
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log("val_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss

  def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
    labels = batch["labels"]
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log("test_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss

  def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
    
    labels = []
    predictions = []
    for output in outputs:
      for out_labels in output["labels"].detach().cpu():
        labels.append(out_labels)
      for out_predictions in output["predictions"].detach().cpu():
        predictions.append(out_predictions)

    labels = torch.stack(labels).int()
    predictions = torch.stack(predictions)

    for i, name in enumerate(LABEL_COLUMNS):
      class_roc_auc = auroc(predictions[:, i], labels[:, i])
      self.logger.experiment.add_scalar(f"{name}_roc_auc/Train", class_roc_auc, self.current_epoch)


  def configure_optimizers(self):

    optimizer = optim.RAdam(self.parameters(), lr=2e-4)

    scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
      optimizer,
      num_warmup_steps=self.n_warmup_steps,
      num_training_steps=self.n_training_steps
    )

    return dict(
      optimizer=optimizer,
      lr_scheduler=dict(
        scheduler=scheduler,
        interval='step'
      )
    )
```

**Sample Data**

```
sample_batch = next(iter(DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=10, num_workers=2)))
sample_batch["input_ids"].shape, sample_batch["attention_mask"].shape

(torch.Size([10, 512]), torch.Size([10, 512]))
sample_batch.keys()
dict_keys(['text_data', 'input_ids', 'attention_mask', 'labels'])
```

**Model**

```
model = SRTagger(
  n_classes=100,
  n_warmup_steps=warmup_steps,
  n_training_steps=total_training_steps 
)
```

**ONNX code**

```
# # Export the model
torch.onnx.export(model,                     # model being run
                  ##since model is in the cuda mode, input also need to be
                  (sample_batch["input_ids"],sample_batch["attention_mask"]),              # model input (or a tuple for multiple inputs)
                  "model_torch_export.onnx", # where to save the model (can be a file or file-like object)
                  export_params=True,        # store the trained parameter weights inside the model file
                  opset_version=10,          # the ONNX version to export the model to
                  do_constant_folding=True,  # whether to execute constant folding for optimization
                  input_names = ['input'],   # the model's input names
                  output_names = ['output'], # the model's output names
                  dynamic_axes={'input' : {0 : 'batch_size'},    # variable lenght axes
                                'output' : {0 : 'batch_size'}})
```

**Error**

RuntimeError: output 1 (0
[ CPULongType{} ]) of traced region did not have observable data dependence with trace inputs; this probably indicates your program cannot be understood by the tracer.

Answer (score 1):

Cuz at onnx conversion, the model output must be tensor, not list, tuple, or dict. You can check your forward of model.

Answer (score 0):

It is only suppressing the error. When I do that, it is memorising output of the sample which is given during torch.onnx.export().

[Details](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-output-1-of-traced-region-did-not-have-observable-data-dependence-with-trace-inputs-this-probably-indicates-your-program-cannot-be-understood-by-the-tracer/94056/6)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that? Please clarify and add details to your answer